# Storing data from an array into the hard disk with I/O expressions (Java)

Tags: java, performance

i'm developing an application for a bookstore, like buying, selling, searching books...etc

now i need to store/retrieve my information from the array to/from the hard disk but without using files (I/O expressions) because it corresponds to a sequential behavior which will affect the speed or performance of my app, i need something like a random memory access!!

any suggestions ?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense... While your program is running, that array is in RAM. When you store it on disk, you HAVE TO store in a file (that's why it's called a **file** system). If I/O performance is an issue, then I suggest using a RAID0 configuration or a SSD.

Comment: You want random memory access performance, to/from your hard disk?

Comment: This is Java, not some low-level C (no offense). Java is based on classes, not direct access to memory, you can try another language.

Comment: Thanks folks but i'll try using a database ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a database, and find one that fits your performance requirements.